# neo4j slow query performance

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have two node (Job and JobSeeker) that i am loading from a csv file . 
I have one more entity called Interest which define relationship between these two entity . Interest has id of Job and JobSeeker through which i can create a SHOW_INTEREST relationship . Total entity count mentioned below

```
Job - 4k
JobSeeker - 80k
Interest - 4.4 Million
```

I am trying to create a query for Collabrative Filtering (**Top 5 Jobs shown interest by similar JobSeekers** ) but it is taking alot time to execute . Can any please help me to figure out what is the problem with this query ? Mention below all the queries .

```
CREATE INDEX ON :Job(_id)
CREATE INDEX ON :JobSeeker(_id)

// Job Node 
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "job.csv" AS j1
MERGE (job:Job {title : "Job",_id:j1._id, jobTitle:j1.title , company: j1.companyName })

// JobSeeker Node 
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "jobSeeker.csv" AS row
CREATE (p:JobSeeker { name : "JobSeeker",_id:row._id,email:row.email, role: row.role,rating:row.rating, firstNamw : row.firstName,sonicScore:row.coreOfJobSeeker
,hiredCount:row.numberOfTimesHired})

// Interest Relationship between Job and JobSeeker 
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "interest.csv" AS row WITH row LIMIT 10000
MATCH (jobSeeker:JobSeeker),(job:Job)
WHERE jobSeeker._id = row.jobSeekerId AND job._id = row.jobId
CREATE (jobSeeker)-[r:SHOWN_INTEREST]->(job)
RETURN type(r)


// Collabrative Filtering
// Top 5 Jobs shown interest by similar JobSeekers
MATCH (s1:JobSeeker{_id:"579c914fe4b00d9fa5d60fb0"})-[:SHOWN_INTEREST]->(j1:Job)<-[:SHOWN_INTEREST]-(s2:JobSeeker),
         (s2:JobSeeker)-[:SHOWN_INTEREST]->(j2:Job)
WHERE NOT (s1)-[:SHOWN_INTEREST]->(j2)
WITH j2 , count(distinct j2) as frequency
ORDER BY frequency DESC LIMIT 5
RETURN j2.jobTitle , frequency
```

PROFILE : https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxyiy.jpg

Answer (score 0):

It may be easier to collect the jobs s1 has shown interest in, that way we can use set filtering instead of expansion to weed out those jobs at the end:

```
MATCH (s1:JobSeeker{_id:"579c914fe4b00d9fa5d60fb0"})-[:SHOWN_INTEREST]->(j1)
WITH s1, collect(j1) as interestedJobs
MATCH (s1)-[:SHOWN_INTEREST*3]-(j2:Job)
WHERE NOT j2 in interestedJobs
WITH j2 , count(j2) as frequency 
ORDER BY frequency DESC 
LIMIT 5 
RETURN j2.jobTitle , frequency
```

Comment: query returning no result .

Comment: PROFILE the query, see at which operation the rows drop to 0

Comment: MATCH (s1)-[:SHOWN_INTEREST*2]-(j2:Job) is dropping to 0

Comment: Got it, my fault there. Two :SHOWN_INTERESTS hops gets you to another :JobSeeker, we need one additional hop to get to the :Job node. Fixed by changing it to *3.